# Workaround for Wildcard pattern hits.* cannot be used to refer to fields in a union

Tags: google-bigquery

The data that comes out from the BigQuery implementation of [GoogleAnalytics raw data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) has multiple repeated fields. To access a sample DB set on BigQuery [read here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416091?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089) it's free.

```
|- fullVisitorId
+- hits
    +- eCommerceAction
    +- customVariables
    +- customDimensions
    +- customMetrics
    +- product
        +- customDimensions
        +- customMetrics
    +- promotion
    +- experiment
```

when using this query:

```
from flatten((select hits.*,fullVisitorId from (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([0.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-01-12'), TIMESTAMP('2017-01-13'))) ),hits)
```

we get:

`Error: 0.0 - 0.0: Wildcard pattern hits.* cannot be used to refer to fields in a union`

What would be an applicable workaround to overcome this nasty error.

Comment: is it mandatory in your project to use the Legacy SQL version? Maybe solving this one in Standard would be a bit easier.

Comment: we have thousands of legacy queries to port

Comment: You don't need to port all of them at once, though, right? It's probably easier in this case to translate whatever other logic the query uses to standard SQL instead of battling with `FLATTEN`, which has a number of corner cases like this.

Comment: I am still looking to find a workaround for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Use standard SQL instead (this is probably the most maintainable option).
- Enumerate all columns explicitly instead of using `.*` inside the `FLATTEN`.
- Use filters such as `OMIT RECORD IF` or scoped aggregations rather than flattening.
- Use a "flattening" operator such as `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` to remove the repetition. This will probably have a performance impact, though.